# How to change case for such a case like this?

Tags: regex, sed

I'd like to use sed or something similar to read in a text file and change all instances of uppercase phrases to lowercase wrapped with \textsc{ **** }.

Eg:

```
THIS SENTENCE IS ALL CAPS except not really
```

should become

```
\textsc{this sentence is all caps} except not really
```

If

```
This Sentence Has Many Caps
```

Should remain

```
This Sentence Has Many Caps
```

with this pattern `s/\(.[A-Z]*\)/textsc{\L\1}/`, the string just change the first word.

Could anyone point me a proper way ?

***Updated:*** The regex pattern should cover apostrophes as well

```
I'll BUY YOU A DRINK
```

Most of solution break down letter ***I*** and ***'*** like this `\textsc{i}'ll \textsc{buy you a} \textsc{drink}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it should work for you.

```
echo "THIS sentence IS ALL CAPS Except not really BUT THIS IS" | \
  sed -re "s/\b(([A-Z]+ [A-Z]+)+)\b/\\\textsc{\L\1}/g"
```

This results in this phrase:

```
THIS sentence \textsc{is all caps} Except not really \textsc{but this is}
```

The `/g` is for a global replace (not just the first match). The `\b` says that a phrase must begin and end on a word boundary (not in the middle of a word). The three slashes before `textsc` are escapes (of escapes) to produce the final `\textsc`. The `([A-Z]+ [A-Z]+)+` is to capture an all-caps phrase. I first tried adding a space into the character class, as in `[A-Z ]`, but this resulted in a space before the curly brace, as in `\text{this sentence }`. So I built the space into the middle of the words to create a phrase.

Note that this leaves isolated uppercased words alone. I assumed that was intended since the questions asks about "phrases". But if you need to replace those as well, try this one:

```
echo "THIS sentence IS ALL CAPS Except not really BUT THIS IS" | \
  sed -re "s/\b((([A-Z]+ [A-Z]+)+)|[A-Z]+)\b/\\\textsc{\L\1}/g"
```

which results in

```
\textsc{this} sentence \textsc{is all caps} Except not really \textsc{but this is}
```

Comment: It seems nice for the first script, but it fails with the case "THIS SENTENCE Has Many Caps", the output is `"\textsc{this sentence h}as Many Caps`

Comment: Updated my answer to handle this case. Added the \b's into the regex

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat file
THIS SENTENCE IS ALL CAPS except not really
This Sentence Has Many Caps
THIS SENTENCE Has Many Caps

$ awk -f tst.awk file
\textsc{this sentence is all caps} except not really
This Sentence Has Many Caps
\textsc{this sentence} Has Many Caps

$ cat tst.awk
{
   while ( match( $0, /([[:upper:]]{2,}[[:space:]]*)+/) ) {
      rstart  = RSTART
      rlength = RLENGTH

      if ( match( substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH), /[[:space:]]+$/) ) {
         rlength = rlength - RLENGTH
      }

      $0 = substr($0,1,rstart-1) \
           "\\textsc{" tolower(substr($0,rstart,rlength)) "}" \
           substr($0,rstart+rlength)
   }

   print
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/\b[A-Z]+\b( *\b[A-Z]+\b)*/\\textsc{\L&}/g' file
```